# Convert date format to another date in Android?

Tags: java, android, date

I am getting date in 2011-10-01T21:00:00.0000000-07:00 format from the server. I have tried to convert that using "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" this format of SimpleDateFormat class. But it always gives me Parser exception.

Can someone tell me what may be wrong in converting it?

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssSSSSSZ");
Date eventDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
```

The above code gives the error.

Comment: Always include the full exception and a code snippet - preferrably an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: I have added the code snippet which is giving the exception.

Comment: Add the exception too, including stack trace.  What you consider irrelevant detail may be useful to somebody diagnosing the issue.  (It is a good habit to be thorough when submitting for online help.)

Comment: Make sure the date you're parsing EXACTLY matches your `SimpleDateFormat` pattern.

Comment: What does the variable `date` contain ?

Comment: date will contain the 2011-10-01T21:00:00.0000000-07:00 value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Capital S expects roughly 1 to 3 characters and over there you have seven characters. This is probably the problem. If milliseconds are not important try removing them. If you want to try something random try putting seven S in there and see if it helps.

P.S. in the code snippet above you are missing the dot between ss and SSSS

Comment: Seven Ss won't work.  Just tried it.  Bumped you up, though.  I agree that's probably the issue.

Comment: Even I think that is the issue but that's the response I am getting from the server.

Comment: The server response do not have the dot too between ss and SSS and that's the reason I removed it, but still no successs.

Comment: "Even I think that is the issue".  Then give the answer a check and move on.  It should be pretty straightforward to break that down with a java.util.StringTokenizer

Comment: Earl StringTokenize I know and love. However it was deprecated and replace with String.split() which takes a regex.

Comment: Sorry Earl, it's not deprecated, however from the api: StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

Comment: Actually... I take it back.  The easiest thing to do is to concatenate two substrings of the date... just snip out the extra zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Your format is wrong: in the string `2011-10-01T21:00:00.0000000-07:00` you have too many millisecond bytes. The `SSS` format string requires exactly 3 zeros (you can't have more than 3 significant figures for a millisecond count).

Check the server format.